# 'Nant' as not recognized command on Jenkins Mac Slave

Tags: macos, shell, jenkins, nant, jenkins-agent

I have a Jenkins's master-slave structure setup created having Master on windows server, plus few windows slaves and one Mac-slave.
The flow is like this,

1. Jenkins shell script triggers a shell command (sh sample.command) [this is used on both windows(using win-bash) and mac node.....]

> The first step where it triggers the shell script is working fine on both windows and mac slave.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo “This is a shell script acting as a middleware to trigger the NAnt....”
echo "Calling NAnt...."
nant ${1} ${2} ${3} ${4}
```

2.Now, the sample.command has a code to trigger a nant command, which is not   working on **mac slave** and giving me an error :
**nant: command not found**

3.The NAnt is installed on the Mac-slave through brew and when I trigger this shell script sample.command from the Mac machine, it works fine and executes the nant command, but doesn't work through jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting up the $PATH variable at the beginning of the shell script. Just added the below line in the shell script,

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet/bin
```

The Paths mentioned here might be different on other machines, what I did is, I checked the $PATH while calling the shell from Mac machine and copy-pasted and that worked.